# Does MQL5 code-execution environment support running also an MQL4-code?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, mql5, metatrader5

Does **`MQL5`** code-execution environment ( <kbd>**`MetaTrader Terminal 5`**</kbd> ) support running also **`MQL4`**-code ?

If I write an `MQL5` code, it will work in <kbd>`MetaTrader Terminal` **`4`**</kbd>;
but
 if I write an `MQL4` code, **will this work in** <kbd>`MetaTrader Terminal 5`</kbd>**?**

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. Provide us with some more information and some examples.

Comment: You may want to direct this question to Meta Quotes.

Comment: With all due respect, this is **absolutely clear** for domain-experts, what Fadi is asking about. It is a sign of one's professional integrity not to blindly mentor ( the less object ) in domains outside of ones expertise, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No, it will not.

**`MQL4`** started it's "secret transition" towards `MQL5` syntax / concept foundations very surprisingly & painfully somewhere around `Build-6xx+`

There is zero motivation for MetaQuotes, Inc., to reverse & block this marketing driven shift by re-engineering of the <kbd>`MetaTrader Terminal 5`</kbd> code-execution environment so as to become "backward compatible".

---

### Epilogue

**If interested in more details**, one may like other posts on impacts on code-base in these posts [on **how painfull was an`MQL4` shift towards `MQL5`-syntax** since it had started and was creeping forward](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3666197%20MQL4.56789).